# php code needed for menu link

Tags: magento-1.9

I had to create a static menu link in `menu.html`. which is linked to a static pages content (with # tag `<li><a href="#sc">Shop</a></li>`).

when I click on that menu, it goes to that content. (URL changes to-- `www.domain.com/#sc`) then, when I click on another menu, it goes to that. but, when I again want to go back to  that (# tagged) menu, it doesnt go (URL changes to-- `www.domain.com/contacts#sc`).

I think, the static menu link should be in php code. but, I cant write 
the code. any one please will me writing the code?

Answer (score 2):

In your `menu.phtml` you have added your Shop menu like this.

```
<a href="#sc">Shop</a>
```

Due to this, it will append `#sc` to the current url, when you click on the page menu link. ie in your home page URL will look like `www.domain.com/#sc`. In your contact page it will look like `www.domain.com/contact/#sc` and so on.

You can fix this by using Magento's *URL generation methods/factory methods*. For this, what you need to do is,

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . '#sc' ?>">Shop</a>
```

### or

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl() . '#sc' ?>">Shop</a>
```

For more reference, ***[you can use this](https://techbandhu.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/magento-get-directory-paths-get-base-urls-get-urls-in-static-block-get-secure-url/)***.

Comment: hi, Rajeev Bro, its done. thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: @e-BizVillage feel free to accept anyone of the answer which helped you to solve your issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are modifying a .phtml file for your stores theme.

Most blocks (Blocks are php classes in Magento that are responsible for handling visual components of the store, Blocks are a part of the V in MVC) in Magento inherit from the `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` class, which gives them access to the:

`public function getUrl($route = '', $params = array())` method

This means you can create URLs for any links in your .phtml template files easily by using the following code `$this->getUrl()`. That function will return the base domain of the current active store view that is loaded.

**Example Usage:**
I want to link to the shipping policy page from the footer of my website, and I want the link to be anchored to the Free Shipping clause which is in an element with the `id="free-shipping"`

In `footer.phtml`

```
<a
    href="<?=$this->getUrl('shipping-policy')?>#free-shipping"
    title="Free Shipping Policy"
>Free Shipping Policy</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter bro. I followed your way, and its done. thanks again.

Comment: No problem, @e-Biz Village! If the answer is correct, please give it a tick to show that its been solved.

Answer (score 1):

To add fragment in your URL , you can use following code

```
$this->getUrl('', array('_fragment' => 'your fragment'));
```

This function is defined in  [Mage_Core_Model_Url](https://github.com/rmsundar1/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php) class